# Rearranging arrays into a table to print into a text file

Tags: c

I have two arrays where one hold the real and the other holds the imaginary value. I am trying to print them in a column where the first real and imaginary values are in the same row, the second values in the second row and so on. Input looks like the following:

```
char real_val[15]={'2',' ','6',' ','2',' ','7',' ','8',' ',' ',' '};
char imag_val[15]={'1','2','5',' ','9',' ','3',' ','7',' ','6',' '};
```

output needs to look like this:

```
   2     125
   6       9
   2       3
   7       7
   8       6
```

I have tried breaking the arrays into tokens and printing but i get an error saying "invalid read size of 1" when the code hits line 18 of the following code:

```
1   #include <stdio.h>
2   #include <stdlib.h>
3   #include <string.h>
4   
5   int main () {
6   int p,q,r, real_count, imag_count; 
7   char real_val[15]={'2',' ','6',' ','2',' ','7',' ','8',' ',' ',' '};
8   char imag_val[15]={'1','2','5',' ','9',' ','3',' ','7',' ','6',' '};
9   real_count = 0;
10  imag_count = 0;
11  const char delimiter[1] = {' '};
12  char output_array[8][2] = {'0'};
13  char *real_token;
14  char *imag_token;
15  int n = 0;
16  
17  
18  real_token = strtok(real_val,' ');
19  imag_token = strtok(imag_val,' ');
20  
21  while(real_token !=NULL){
22    n++;
23    real_token = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
24    imag_token = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
25  }
26  }
```

I have also attempted to manually do this through the creation of a 3-d array

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main () {
int m,n,p,r,t, real_count, imag_count; 
char real_val[15]={'2',' ','6',' ','2',' ','7',' ','8',' ',' ',' '};
char imag_val[15]={'1','2','5',' ','9',' ','3',' ','7',' ','6',' '};
char array1[8]= {'0'};
char array2[8]={'0'};
int q = 0;
int s = 0;
char output_array[1][2][8]= {'0'};


for(m=0;m<sizeof(real_val);m++){

for(p=0;p<sizeof(real_val);p++){
 if (real_val[p] != ' ' && real_val[p] != '\0'){
    array1[q] = real_val[p];
    q++;

  }
 else{
   for(n=q;n<8;n++){
     array1[n]= 0;
   }
  for(t=0;t<8;t++){
  output_array[m][0][t] = array1[t];
  }
  q=0;
}
}  
for(r=0;r<sizeof(imag_val);r++){
    if (imag_val[r] != ' ' && imag_val[r] != '\0'){
    array2[s] = imag_val[r];
    s++;
    }
  else{
   for(n=s;n<8;n++){
     array2[n]= 0;
   }  
  for(t=0;t<8;t++){
  output_array[m][1][t] = array2[t];
  }
  r=0;  

  //strcat(array1,array2);
  fprintf("%s", output_array);

 }
}


}  
}
```

But after many changes and my brain hurting I gave up on this. Any direction on how I can achieve this seemingly simple problem would be greatly appreciated. It would be a lot easier if the number of digits between the real and imaginary were the same but they vary.

Thank you in advance. And if I forgot details feel free to ask.

Comment: It would also be a lot easier if you use the same arrays in your tests, even though they might be vary from one run to another. If you want to debug: don't walk on shifting sand.

Comment: done. I know the second code has many mistakes, I just don't know how to get the first real number of interest and the first imaginary number of interest and somehow print these then move to the second numbers and so forth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strtok` accepts a string containing list of delimiters, not a single character.
To get rid of compilation error you need to replace:

`real_token = strtok(real_val,' ');`

with

`real_token = strtok(real_val," ");`

And the same with other occurences.

Also, you cannot mix two tokenizations, you need to split first string, and then second one. You can store results of both tokenizations in two arrays of char* and then iterate over them during printing. So something like this:

```
char *real_token[50], *imag_token[50];
real_token[0] = strtok(real_val," "); 
n = 1;
while (real_token[n-1] != NULL) {
    real_token[n] = strtok(NULL, " ");
    n++;
}
imag_token[0] = strtok(imag_val," ");
n = 1;
while(imag_token[n-1] != NULL){
    imag_token[n] = strtok(NULL, " ");
    n++;
}

// here loop from 0 to n and print
```

Comment: Perfect thank you, I have fixed it and I am able to go point to each token successfully. The only problem left is how I can print them in the format described above since my loops run through all real numbers before beginning the imaginary array.

Comment: You can simply `for (i = 0; i < n; i++) printf("%s %s\n", real_token[i], imag_token[i]);`. Or expand the loop and print each part in separate print, and additionally print as many spaces as required for your formatting before first part and between parts.